Grouping items in a list based on attribute values inside a mustache template
Say I had a list of 'bookings':
[
  {
    Date: { S: '2024-04-10' },
    BookingID: { N: '3' },
    Room: { S: 'Pod1' }
  },
  {
    Date: { S: '2024-04-10' },
    BookingID: { N: '5' },
    Room: { S: 'Pod2' }
  },
  {
    Date: { S: '2024-05-13' },
    BookingID: { N: '2' },
    Room: { S: 'Pod3' }
  }
]

How would I format my mustache file to group bookings together depending on their date for example?
Would I have to use a script? I can display the list on my mustache file using:
{{#bookings}}
  <p>Date: {{date}}
  <p>ID: {{id}}
  <p>Room: {{room}}
{{/bookings}}

But I'm not sure where I'd even start to be able to group them together by date.
Apologies if this wasn't worded the best, I'm still getting used to writing decent questions here! TIA

You can use a JS function to group the bookings and pass the grouped bookings to the mustache file.


const bookings = [
    {
        Date: { S: "2024-04-10" },
        BookingID: { N: "3" },
        Room: { S: "Pod1" }
    },
    {
        Date: { S: "2024-04-10" },
        BookingID: { N: "5" },
        Room: { S: "Pod2" }
    },
    {
        Date: { S: "2024-05-13" },
        BookingID: { N: "2" },
        Room: { S: "Pod3" }
    }
];

// Group bookings by date
let groupedBookings = {};
bookings.forEach(function (booking) {
    const date = booking.Date.S;
    if (!groupedBookings[date]) {
        groupedBookings[date] = [];
    }
    groupedBookings[date].push(booking);
});

groupedBookings = Object.entries(groupedBookings).map(([date, bookings]) => ({
    date,
    bookings
}));

console.log(groupedBookings);



In your mustache file you can make it look something like this:
{{#groupedBookings}}
    <h2>{{date}}</h2>

    {{#bookings}}
        <p>Date: {{Date}}</p>
        <p>ID: {{BookingID}}</p>
        <p>Room: {{Room}}</p>
    {{/bookings}}
{{/groupedBookings}}


I understand your logic, but I don't think that's working. If I render the page like:
res.render("AllBookings", {
"groupedBookings" : groupedBookings,
"bookings" : bookings,
});
They don't appear ordered

and rendering it only using "groupedBookings" and not "bookings" doesn't show anything.

That happens because mustache cannot access nested properties. I'll update my answer.

You only have to pass "groupedBookings": groupedBookings to the file.

The individual values have to be accessed like Date: {{Date.S}} in the mustache template, but yes your answer was a great help, thank you very much
